# MySql string replace query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

If I run this query I get back several rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where `post_content` like '%http://www.youtube%'
```

However when I run the query below, it says 0 rows effected.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'%http://www.youtube%','%https://www.youtube%')
WHERE `post_content` like '%http://www.youtube%'
```

I am using PhpMyAdmin hosted on WP Engine.  Their support say there is no restrictions on updating multiple rows.

What is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `%` inside the replace:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'http://www.youtube','https://www.youtube')
WHERE `post_content` like '%http://www.youtube%'
```

Comment: Thanks.  So obvious yet I didn't see it.  I'll accept soon as timer runs out.